# Conditional fields in wordpress registration

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, registration

I have added some customized registration fields to my website by using the code below.

1. I am looking to also add a field of 'country' selection. What code is needed to be added to the code below to have 'billing country'select dropdown option to be added.
2. I'd like to add a conditional that if 'united states' is chosen, only then, the the two fields for "licence number" and "agd" will show, and otherwise will remain hidden.

Please advise and let me know if my question is clear enough. thank you in advance :)

```
function wooc_extra_register_fields() {?>
       <p class="form-row form-row-first">
       <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <p class="form-row form-row-last">
       <label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
       <label for="reg_billing_phone"><?php _e( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_phone'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <div class="clear"></div>
       <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
       <label for="reg_license_number"><?php _e( 'License Number', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="license_number" id="reg_license_number" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $_POST['license_number'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <div class="clear"></div>
       <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
       <label for="reg_agd"><?php _e( 'AGD ID', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="agd" id="reg_agd" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $_POST['agd'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <div class="clear"></div>
       <?php
 }
 add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'wooc_extra_register_fields' );


/**
* register fields Validating.
*/
function wooc_validate_extra_register_fields( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {
      if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
             $validation_errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: First name is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
      }
      if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
             $validation_errors->add( 'billing_last_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Last name is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
      }
          if ( isset( $_POST['reg_billing_phone'] ) && empty( $_POST['reg_billing_phone'] ) ) {
             $validation_errors->add( 'billing_phone_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Phone is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
      }


         return $validation_errors;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'wooc_validate_extra_register_fields', 10, 3 );




/**
* Below code save extra fields.
*/
function wooc_save_extra_register_fields( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
                 // Phone input filed which is used in WooCommerce
                 update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) );
          }
      if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
             //First name field which is by default
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
             // First name field which is used in WooCommerce
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
      }
      if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
             // Last name field which is by default
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );
             // Last name field which is used in WooCommerce
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );
      }
          if ( isset( $_POST['license_number'] ) ) {
             // Last name field which is by default
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'license_number', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['license_number'] ) );
             // Last name field which is used in WooCommerce
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'license_number', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['license_number'] ) );
      }
          if ( isset( $_POST['agd'] ) ) {
             // Last name field which is by default
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'agd', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['agd'] ) );
             // Last name field which is used in WooCommerce
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'agd', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['agd'] ) );
      }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'wooc_save_extra_register_fields' );
```

Comment: Duplicate: [Show or hide registration fields based on selected value in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564372/show-or-hide-registration-fields-based-on-selected-value-in-woocommerce)

Comment: Have you tried with jquery code? it's more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Hi suggest to use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-footer/ and add in footer a jquery script that show the "licence number" and "agd" when "united states" is selected.

I make an example

```
jQuery(.license).hide();
jQuery(.agd).hide();

var selected_option = $('select#country option:selected');

$('select#country').on('change', function() {
  if(selected_option=='united states') {
    jQuery(.license).show();
    jQuery(.agd).show();
  } else {
    jQuery(.license).hide();
    jQuery(.agd).hide();
  }
});
```

Let me know

Comment: Gabriele Fagnani thank you so much! The only missing part is to add to my registration the option to select countries. Do you happen to know how i can insert it as another field in the code i provided in my first message?